# Defined on the closure or on a closed set

Tags: general-topology, functions

What are the differences between the two definitions

- Let $f: \bar{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$
  where  $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

and

- Let $f: C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$
  where  $C$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

is there a sens to define a function on a closed subset ?

Comment: Not every closed set is the closure of an open set, just consider the set containing only one point.

Comment: ok, why do we restrict usually to define a function of an open set or a closure of open sets ?
why is it bad to define on closed subset ?

Comment: @Smilia For the simple reason that closed sets can be really nasty, while open sets are nice and predictable. Closures of open sets are, as such, the nicest closed sets.

Comment: Would be usefull to put us in some context to give a more precise answer.